# Independent spacing for ticks and ticklabels?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to have a scatter plot with ticks as marginals:

```
x = [ 0,  1, 1.2, 1.3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.2, 9, 10]
y = [.2, .4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 4, 3, 8]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
for spine in ax1.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)

ax1.scatter(x, y)

ax1.set_xticks(x)
ax1.set_xticklabels([])

ax1.set_yticks(y)
ax1.set_yticklabels([])
```

[image: ticks as marginals]

And on top of that, I want to have ticklabels at other positions, not determined by the ticks:

```
xticklabels = [0, 5, 10]
yticklabels = xticklabels
```

How could I possibly achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib axes have major and minor ticks. You may use the minor ticks to show the marginal locations of the points. You may turn the major ticks off but show the ticklabels for them.

To set ticks at certain positions you can use a [`FixedLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator). To change the appearance of the ticks or turn them off, the axes has a [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = [ 0,  1, 1.2, 1.3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.2, 9, 10]
y = [.2, .4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 4, 3, 8]

xticklabels = [0, 5, 10]
yticklabels = xticklabels

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)

ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(xticklabels))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(yticklabels))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(x))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(y))

ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="major", bottom="off", left="off")
ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="minor", length=4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that I personally find this plot rather difficult to grasp and if I may, I would propose something more like this:

[image]

```css
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = [ 0,  1, 1.2, 1.3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.2, 9, 10]
y = [.2, .4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 4, 3, 8]

xticklabels = [0, 5, 10]
yticklabels = xticklabels

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(x))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(y))

c = "#aaaaaa"
ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="major", direction="out", color=c)
ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="minor", length=6, direction="in",
           color="C0", width=1.5)
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), color=c)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), color=c)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), color=c)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The answer is really instructive and clear. Thanks for that and for your suggestions